# Find the upper and lower integrals for the function

Tags: calculus, integration, rational-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

Find the upper and lower integrals for the function $f(x)$, where all rational numbers are defined by $x^2$, and all irrationals defined $1$ on the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: you mean the irrationals defined 1 ? there are only 2 integers in that interval....

Comment: @DeepSea, yes! Irrational ones

Comment: $\frac{1}{3}$ and $1$ ?